# Client SSL handshake failed - no cipher suites in common

Tags: ssl, charles-proxy

I can't read SSL traffic. It just says `Client SSL handshake failed`. I've followed numerous guides, and have tried this on both my iPhone (iOS 12.0) and Genymotion Android simulation (android 8.0):

- Modified my wifi HTTP settings to 192.168.2.133:8888
- Installed the SSL cert from chls.pro/ssl
- On the iPhone, went into settings to give the cert full permission
- Right clicked on the instagram.com request under "structure" in charles and enabled SSL proxy

Here's the IP addr and port I'm told to use:
[image]
The first Android device I tried:
[image]
Results:
[image]
[image]
Even on Apple:
[image]
Now again with Android 6.0.0 API 23:
[image]

I thought Android 6.0.0 may fix it because there's a rumor that you can't sniff traffic from a 3rd party app after Android N.

Comment: Did you find solution for this ?

Comment: Where you trying this on your own app? Starting on Android 7 you need an entry in _ AndroidManifest.xml_. See https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html